# how do I use rails time_ago_in_words in backbone template

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, hamlc

Is there a way to use rails standard methods such as time_ago_in_words in backbone template also using hamlc ? When I tried this

```
.created_at= time_ago_in_words e.created_at
```

It throws an exception

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: time_ago_in_words is not defined
```

Comment: Well, no. Unless you rewrite rails helper :time_ago_in_words into javascript function. You would better use momentjs to manipulate with date/time in js.

Comment: Here is javascript port https://gist.github.com/deadkarma/1989808

Answer (score 0):

```
    I had to create this simple method and return to the template. 

     include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper
     def personalize_time(c)
          coll = []
          c.each do |v|
            coll << {"created_at" => time_ago_in_words(v['created_at']), "collection" => v}         
          end
          coll
     end
```